# How do I target a specific node in an xml document using XSLT?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt

Below is a condensed version of a XML file provided by a different business unit. What I need to get the value of is **DriverInputSetGoodStudent**.

This is how I am approaching this:

```
//session/data/policy/line/child::vehicle[position()=1]
```

That gets me the first vehicle in the XML, so then I will know the ID of the driver of that vehicle based on the **GoverningDriverIdInfo/ItemId**. Then I need to match that ID with the **id** property of the **driver** node. Then get the value of the **DriverInputSetGoodStudent** node.

```
<session>
<data>
    <policy>
        <line>
            <driver id="d4A5D51CEC4C14D3C9754A59AE09EFF9B" deleted="0" description="OH Edge, Teresa / 321654654">
                <DriverTrainingInd>N</DriverTrainingInd>
                <DriverInputGoodStudent>N</DriverInputGoodStudent>
                <DriverInputSetDriverTraining>0</DriverInputSetDriverTraining>
                <DriverInputSetGoodStudent>0</DriverInputSetGoodStudent>
                <DriverInputAccidentPreventionTrainingDate>2011-05-05</DriverInputAccidentPreventionTrainingDate>
                <AccidentPreventionCourse>0</AccidentPreventionCourse>
                <AccidentPreventionCoursePreviousValue>0</AccidentPreventionCoursePreviousValue>
                <DriverTrainingPrevValue>0</DriverTrainingPrevValue>
                <DriverOutputGoodStudent>No</DriverOutputGoodStudent>
            </driver>
            <vehicle id="v1CFDF4006D7C41D8B8C8A510E4C5C2E1" deleted="0" description="TYTA CAMRY BASE/LE/SE/XLE, 2010, 4T1BF3EK3AU522985">
                <VehicleInputPrimaryDriver>d4A5D51CEC4C14D3C9754A59AE09EFF9B</VehicleInputPrimaryDriver>
                <GoverningDriverIdInfo>
                  <ItemIdList>d4A5D51CEC4C14D3C9754A59AE09EFF9B</ItemIdList>
                  <ItemId>d4A5D51CEC4C14D3C9754A59AE09EFF9B</ItemId>
                </GoverningDriverIdInfo>
                <PrimaryDriverID>d4A5D51CEC4C14D3C9754A59AE09EFF9B</PrimaryDriverID>
                <VehicleGoodStudent>No</VehicleGoodStudent>
                <VehicleDriverTraining>No</VehicleDriverTraining>
            </vehicle>
        <line>
    <policy>
<data>
<session>
```

I see that the code didn't paste in the quite correctly, there is an "end session" tag that isn't appearing in the code block. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the id somewhere :

```
<xsl:variable name="driverID" select="data/policy/line/child::vehicle[position()=1]/GoverningDriverIdInfo/ItemId"/>
```

You can simply use it to find the desired node :

```
<xsl:variable name="targetNode" select="data/policy/line/driver[@id = $driverID]/DriverInputSetGoodStudent"/>
```

Update answer :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//session">
      <xsl:message terminate="no">
        <xsl:value-of select="data/policy/line/driver[@id = current()/data/policy/line/child::vehicle[position()=1]/GoverningDriverIdInfo/ItemId]/DriverInputSetGoodStudent"/>
      </xsl:message>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output :

```
 [xslt] : Warning! 0
```

Where 0 is the value of your desired node. No variables used. I thought it was clear how to combine the two variables which were used only for proving a concept.

Comment: Ok. Is there any way I can combine the 2 parts into one line without using variables? I need to do this check on 4 vehicles and I'm hoping it can be done without having to create 8 variables for just one section. I'll also have 3 or 4 sections to do this in.